# How can I run an application while another application is running?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I want to run an application when some other application is running. e.g. in a script I start an application:

```
#!/bin/sh
bob
```

and this application will run for a large amount of time. *However*, I want to run another application `alice` (that will be using `bob`'s results) 5 seconds after starting `bob`.
How should I proceed?

Comment: You want to start a program that depends on John's output five seconds after John starts? Either you have a supercomputer capable of cracking hashes in record time, or you're going to need a time machine.

Comment: Why not get the output of the first app result inside a main script, or from a function, part of a main script? Many languages allow this. Python for example. It seems to me your are overcomplicating the issue.

Comment: Put your first application to the background, putting `&` after the command, sleep for five seconds, then start the second application, like `runApplication JOHN &; sleep 5; run-second-application`.

Comment: You might want to look into investing some time reading up on some [shell basics](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0100.php).

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If one of the answers *solved your problem*, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is the most useful of all](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Using the results how?

Comment: Without this information ^, any answer would be a guess.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how `alice` and `bob` are written and how fast each one runs, this might be as easy as:

```
#!/bin/sh
bob &
sleep 5
alice
```

but that has these assumptions:

- `bob` does not lock its output file(s) exclusively
- `bob` runs faster then `alice`
- `alice` does not need the full result set of `bob` to start executing.

If any of the above assumptions is not met, the solution is:

1. Invent a time machine
2. Go back in time a large enough amount of time
3. Start `bob`
4. Come back to current time + 5 seconds
5. Start `alice`

Comment: Note that `bob` may also be outputting to STDOUT, which blocks this answer from working.

Comment: That would be a simple redirect!  @KazWolfe  No Time Travel necessary.

Comment: I’d also consider `wait`ing for the background process to be finished.

Comment: @Melebius: True, but from the original question, that does not look like OPs intention...

Answer (score 1):

> and this application will run for a large amount of time. However, I want to run another application alice (that will be using bob's results) 5 seconds after starting bob.

This seems arbitrary.  If you run `bob | alice`, then `alice` will start immediately processing output from `bob`.  `alice` will process it as fast as `bob` can produce it.

What's your *real question*?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Without more details this question is not able to be answered.